# How to extract specific text from webpage using Kotlin?

Tags: android, html, kotlin

I am working on an Android app using Kotlin. I want to extract the paragraph under **Movie Info** in this link https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/john_wick_chapter_3_parabellum

I can see the content is in the div tag with id=movieSynopsis. How can I extract this text using Kotlin? Thank you!

Comment: How about [skrape.it](https://github.com/skrapeit/skrape.it)?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript in your WebView.
You must enable javascript in your webView. Since it is set to false by default.

After you loaded the url. Then in your webViewClient.

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?){
    val script:String = "javascript:var element = document.getElementById(\"movieSynopsis\");element.textContent;"             
    view?.evaluateJavascript(script) { it ->
        Log.d("DBG", it)
    }
}
```